# how to get node path from JTree when tree is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtree

I have tree with several nodes and also create one tree listener for that,now i need to get the specific node path when it is clicked,
  I have tried this code but didn't get exact output can anybody help me?

```
public class FTListener implements TreeSelectionListener {


    @Override
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        TreePath[] tree=new TreePath[e.getNewLeadSelectionPath().getPathCount()];
        int i=0;

        tree=e.getPaths();

        for(TreePath tr:tree){
            System.out.println(tree[i]);
        i++;}

        //getPath() returns the array elements so i'm here using 
    //for loop for printing each elements.
```

this is the output

```
[/Desktop, /home/user/Desktop, /home/user/Desktop/1302677132563_USER_MANUAL_SMS_BANKING.pdf]
[/Desktop, /home/user/Desktop, /home/user/Desktop/Lab090C .java~]
```

Comment: what's the problem? you have two paths selected and they are both printed, as you coded it :-)

Comment: @kleopatra good thing that a PC still does exactly what we code. I would start worrying otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {

    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)
                       tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

    if (node == null) {
    //since Nothing is selected.     
     return;
    }

    Object nodeObject = node.getUserObject();
    System.out.println("Selected node : " + nodeObject);
}
```

Add this if you want only single selection

```
tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode
        (TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
```

Comment: Why the cast to `DefaultMutableTreeNode` ? It is perfectly possible to create a `JTree` with your own objects.

Comment: @Robin I think that `DefaultMutableXxx` is advantage, but agree with against `to reinvent the wheel`

Comment: @mKorbel I agree that there are a lot of situations where it is easy ot reuse the `DefaultMutableTreeNode`. But in case of this question there is nothing to suggest s/he is using `DefaultMutableTreeNode` instances, which makes this answer too specific.

Comment: @Robin I agree, If he used object as treeNode, tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent().toString() is more than enough.